# Return all objects from a vector

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that contains object names:

```
objlist <- data.frame(col1 = c(a,f,g), col2 = c(z,h,b))
```

Each object is a single column data frame containing numbers like so:

```
a
1.7
3.4
7.7
8.2
```

I would like to create a data frame which contains the values within the objects "cbind'ed" together.  Each data frame is the same count of rows.

I have tried an lapply function like the one below to no avail.

```
objvals <- function(x) { 
                        return(x)
                       }
objvals(objlist)
```

Comment: Do you want the result to be `cbind(a,f,g,z,h,b)`?  Or 3 separate objects: `cbind(a,z)`, `cbind(f,h)`, `cbind(g,b)`?

Comment: cbind(a,f,g,z,h,b)

Answer (score 1):

Original solution:

```
sapply(unlist(objlist), get)
```

Better solution from @Onyambu:

```
data.frame(mget(unlist(objlist)))
```

Example:

```
objlist <- data.frame(
    col1 = c("a", "f", "g"), 
    col2 = c("z", "h", "b"), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

a <- f <- g <- z <- h <- b <- 1:10

data.frame(mget(unlist(objlist)))
```

Comment: `data.frame(mget(unlist(objlist)))` this can help you out